# How to keep JPopupMenu from closing?

Tags: java, swing

I've created a 'date picker' component which is simply a controller (`JComponent`) and a display (`JPopupMenu` extension). I would like for the display popup to remain showing when the user controls the date with the arrows. I've tried calling `popup.show(...)` on `mouseReleased` of the buttons in an attempt to reset the popup, but it doesn't hide as usual afterwards. How can I achieve this while maintaining the usual behaviour of `JPopupMenu`?

Sure I could use `JWindow`, but then I would have to worry about emulating the show/hide behaviour of a `JPopupMenu` using focus etc. which I would very much like to avoid.

Thank you. :)

[image]

**SSCCEE**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PopupSSCCE {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel controller = new JPanel();
    private JLabel controllerLabel = new JLabel("Controller");
    private JLabel display = new JLabel("Display");
    private JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    private JButton prev = new JButton("<");
    private JButton next = new JButton(">");

    private PopupSSCCE() {
        controllerLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (controllerLabel.contains(e.getPoint()))
                    popup.show(controllerLabel, -50, controllerLabel.getHeight());
            }
        });

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 300));
        popup.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        controller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
        prev.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        next.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        controllerLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        controller.add(prev);
        controller.add(controllerLabel);
        controller.add(next);
        popup.add(display);
        frame.getContentPane().add(controller);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PopupSSCCE();
    }
}
```

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is much more use than a screenshot.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sure an SSCCE would be useful, but it's not easy to extract the component out of the application. Surely a suggested approach might be easy enough without an SSCCE.

Comment: I (generally) don't suggest anything unless I can first test it in code.  Especially something 'a little out of the ordinary' that I have not tried before.  Hey, but it's your problem & your choice.

Comment: That's fair enough actually, I understand that it's not a common problem. I'll create a functional SSCCEE (won't look like my one but should behave the same way)

Comment: *"(won't look like my one but should behave the same way)"*  That's the main thing that is required to call it an ssccE. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Okay I think that should do it. :)

Comment: replace JPopup with JWindow, add [take Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/), [escape](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/escape-key-and-dialog/), on `FocusLost` override to `JWindow#setVisible()`, don't implements double mouse click (user non friendly)

Comment: @mKorbel JWindow does not receive focus though?

Comment: without visible JFrame not, but if is there JPanel or any JComponents, if you don't play with that then without any issue with un_decorated JDialog, btw did you load sourcecode for Calendar by Toedter, there is bunch code lines for Focus recycle

Answer (score 3):

- don't use `JPopup` or `Popup` container as base for non_homework code,
- from `Java4` isn't possible to manage "Stay popup on the screen" from JComboBox, JMenu, JPopupMenu, [more here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/combo-box-no-action/)
- use exist and non_buggy code by [Toedter](http://toedter.com/) or [SwingX](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kschaefe/archive/2012/02/02/swingx-163-released) made by [kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203657/kleopatra)
- important don't to try reinvent the wheel